# Using manipulate to observe vectors in a plane

Tags: manipulate

How could I add a text with the coordinates at the ends of vectors?

```
Manipulate[ Graphics3D[{{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}]},
        {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{vermelho, 0}}]}, 
        {Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{azul, 0}}]}}, 
        SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> .37], 
    {{vermelho, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{azul, {0, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
    ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Description

This can be achieved in a number of ways. Here is an example with `Text`

### Example

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   {Blue, Opacity[.5], Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}]},
   {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{vermelho, 0}}]},
   {Black, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{azul, 0}}]},

   Style[Text[#, #] & @ Flatten @ {vermelho, 0}, 16],
   Style[Text[#, #] & @ Flatten @ {azul, 0}, 16],

   }, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> .37
  ],
 {{vermelho, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 {{azul, {0, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

### Output

[image: output example]

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
     Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}]}, {Red,
      Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{vermelho, 0}}]}, {Black, 
     Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{azul, 0}}]}}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> .37, 
   Text[Panel["text", FrameMargins -> 0], Flatten@{vermelho, 0}], 
   Text[Panel["text", FrameMargins -> 0], 
    Flatten@{azul, 0}]}], {{vermelho, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{azul, {0, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```